# Unstack columns in a double clustered column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have two series that I want to visualize using a clustered column chart. Because of different scale I want a left side and right side axis. However, when I use the combo chart with 2 clusted columns and one on the secondary axis the two columns are on top of each other (see picture). I tried increasing/decreasing the gap width and increasing/decreasing the series overlap. The latter had no effect at all.

[image: Example]

SAMPLE DATA:

```
Excess  Sharpe ratio
3.02%   2.55
1.17%   1.30
-   -
-   -
-   -
-0.63%  0.71
```

Visualisation I want, but with a secondary axis to solve scaling issues. 
[image: End]

Comment: Do you have a sample data and the illustration of the outcome that you want? Btw, to get what you want, you will need to graph both data in both axis. Then just set to transparent the series you want hidden. So in primary axix, you both have LHS and RHS with RHS hidden (transaparent). Second axis with LHS and RHS but with LHS transparent or hidden. So you have 4 series really but only shows 2.

Comment: I guess that does somewhat work, however my primary axis that is supposed to show the excess return is scaled to the sharpe ratio, which is 100 times higher.

Comment: You will have to adjust it manually for both axis. Also you need to set the both axis scaling ratio to be the same. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdwZv.png) what I did using your sample data. Take note that I already deleted the excess legend and made the extra series transparent.

Comment: It shouldn't. If it is transparent, it should be transparent. Make sure you have the same scaling ratio on both axes as I've pointed out in my 2nd comment. As you can see in the photo I posted, the primary axis scales from -1% to 5% while the other is from -0.5 to 2.5. That is to make sure your zeros are aligned in both axes.